# Tag appears to be interpreted as part of a link and thus breaking the link

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags

We have a link on our home page going to a subdomain like so:

```
dogs.example.com?_ga=1.231775647.1813887044.1412445362
```

But this produces a 404 error "Cannot find page "_ga=1.231775647.1813887044.1412445362".

If I remove the tag and just navigate to dogs.example.com the page does load. So for some reason the browser is interpreting the tag as part of the link.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are producing a relative link, not an full http link which you need to change domains try the following:

```
href="//dogs.example.com?_ga=1.231775647.1813887044.1412445362"
```